# How can I render only once an Alert component in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

How can I render only one time an Alert component in react native if my dashboardScreen is being render many times?

I'm using Context api, if I dispatch an action it causes another render, if I use a useState it causes another render/renders, any idea will be highly appreciate it.

```
**AppContext.js**
export const AppContext = createContext();

export const AppProvider = ({ children })=> { 

const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer( appReducer, appInicialState);

 return (
        <AppProvider.Provider value={{
            ...state,
        }}>
            { children }
        </AppProvider.Provider>
    )

}

**Dashboard.js**
export const Dashboard = () => {
 const { state, dispatch } = useContext( AppContext );
 const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(true);

 const handleCancelPressed = () => {
      dispatch({ 
            type: 'cancelPressed',
            payload: {
                userInfo: false,
            }
        });
 }

 const handleAcceptPressed = () => {
      dispatch({ 
            type: 'acceptPressed',
            payload: {
                userInfo: true,
            }
        });
 }

 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {showAlert && (
         Alert.alert(
    "Alert Title",
    "My Alert Msg",
    [
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        onPress: handleCancelPressed,
      },
 {
        text: "Ok",
        onPress: handleAcceptPressed ,
      },
    ],
    {
      cancelable: true,
    }
  );
    )}
  </View>

)}
```

Comment: When do you want this alert to be triggered once and displayed? Can you walk us through the UI and when and what should happen?

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is the way which can solve your problem for rendering it only once.

```
const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(null);

useEffect(()=>{setShowAlert(true)},[])
```

The empty bracket denotes that, value for 'showAlert' will be set only once.

You should read useEffect in detail for implementing this properly.

I am not trying this example in any coding environment, I have only shared a *proof of concept* for you to work upon.

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Shameel Uddin